# Removing an element from a list in Elm

Tags: linked-list, elm

Basically what I want to do is something like ...

removefromList "A" ["A", "B", "A"] and get back a new list of ["B"]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`List.filter` provides a way to make a new list based on an input list, filtering out elements that don't match the predicate.

```
List.filter (\x -> x /= "A") ["A", "B", "A"]
-- yields: ["B"]
```

Comment: is there a way of doing this using `List.map`?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon no, definitely not - one of the fundamental properties of `map` is that it can't change the number of elements in the list.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon [filterMap](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#filterMap) will allow you to map and filter together.

Answer (score 4):

Just as additional info, the `List.Extra` package provides a variety of list convenience functions such as `remove` (for the first occurrence of an element), `removeAt` (for removing element at an index), `dropWhile`, etc. that may be worth looking into for more complicated removal conditions.

For simple removal of all "A" as you mention `List.filter` would be most simple and sufficient.